# How to set type of field when inserting into mongodb

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

So I am querying an API, receiving data and then storing it into MongoDB.
All was working fine so far, Except now I have started using Mongo's Aggregation pipeline. During this I realized that Mongo is inserting the number data as strings. Hence now, my aggregation pipeline wont work as I am doing numerical computation such as calculating averages etc....Because Mongo is seeing it as a string.

How can I set the type of the field during Insert.....such that I specify that this is float etc...

What I have tried so far is the below code: but it does not work well, because the mongo shell is complaining because the field name starts with a number:

```
db.weeklycol.find().forEach(function(ch)
{
db.weeklycol.update({
"_id":ch._id},
{"$set":
{
"4_close":parseInt(ch.4_close)
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To access property, which name is weird use []:

```js
ch['4_close']
```

Then about saving numbers, well I made test:

```
> db.test.insertOne({_id:1, field: 2})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "insertedId" : 1 }
> db.test.find({_id:1})
{ "_id" : 1, "field" : 2 }
```

Seems to be added number alright. Can you please post exact example of code with some dummy values where inserted object have property with number value, and inserted document have this value turned to string?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this by the below code....So I changing the variable type before inserting it into my "insert" string with the below code:  I created this function, and I call the function on my whole dictionary just before im inserting....If its a number it will convert, else it will pass:
I have similar function which converts as well....instead of float on line 4, i have it changed to date.

```
def convertint(bdic):
for key, value in bdic.items():
    try:
        bdic[key] = float(value)
    except:
        pass
return bdic
```